# How can I use OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile in Qt 5.4?

Tags: qt, opengl, glsl

I have the following output from `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.7.0-devel (git-e566e52 2015-06-29 vivid-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.7.0-devel (git-e566e52 2015-06-29 vivid-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.7.0-devel (git-e566e52 2015-06-29 vivid-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

and the following from my Qt 5.4 application for my CG class:

```
OpenGL Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.7.0-devel (git-e566e52 2015-06-29 vivid-oibaf-ppa)
GLSL Version: 1.30
```

so how one can use the Core Profile of OpenGL? I really need the GLSL 3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing it inside a widget that's inherited from QOpenGLWidget like this:

```
QSurfaceFormat fmt;
fmt.setVersion( 3, 3 );
fmt.setProfile( QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile );
setFormat( fmt );
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat( fmt );
```